Issue with Azure Container Apps Deployment in Terraform
When attempting to deploy an Azure Container App using Terraform, I encounter the error message:

Cannot remove secrets from Container Apps at this time due to a
limitation in the Container Apps Service. Please see
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/395 for more
details.

Despite not attempting to directly modify any secrets, I'm unable to proceed with the deployment. The closed issue they are mentioning here seems to be related to the problem. But didn't help much. This is something that suddenly started happening without any changes to the code as well.
I'm using the terraform version - 3.101.0
resource "azurerm_container_app" "container_app" {
  name                         = var.app_name
  container_app_environment_id = var.ca_environment
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
  revision_mode                = "Single"

  ingress {
      external_enabled = true
      target_port = var.port
      traffic_weight {
        percentage = 100
        latest_revision = true
      }
  }

  secret {
    name  = "container-registry-password"
    value = var.registry_credentials.registry_key
  }

  registry {
    server   = var.registry_credentials.registry_server_url
    username = var.registry_credentials.registry_username
    password_secret_name = "container-registry-password"
  }

  template {
      container {
        name   = "app-container"
        image  = "${var.registry_credentials.registry_server_url}/${var.image_name}:latest"
        cpu    = 1
        memory = "2Gi"

      dynamic "env" {
        for_each = var.configs
        content {
          name  = env.value.name
          value = env.value.value
        }
      }
      liveness_probe {
        transport               = "HTTP"
        path                    = var.liveness_path
        port                    = var.port
        initial_delay           = 30
        interval_seconds        = 30
        timeout                 = 15
        failure_count_threshold = 3
      }
    }
    min_replicas = 1
    max_replicas = 3
    
  }
}

How can I get this issue resolved?

Hi Kamal Rathnayake, Share the Terraform code, what have you tried?

Hi @VenkatV, Edited the question with the code.

I tried your code, and it seems to be working fine. Here is my result. If you're still encountering issues, you can create the container app using user identity instead of ACR username and password."

@VenkatV, Thanks!. Let me give it a try. The weird thing is this is something that has been working fine. Do you have any theory on why it suddenly stopped working? :D

If the container app was already created earlier with a secret, and you are trying to run the code again, the code will attempt to remove and recreate a secret with the same value. However, this process is failing due to a limitation. Alternatively, you can also create using user identity.

If you are okay with using the Identity method, I will post an answer using the same approach.


When attempting to deploy an Azure Container App using Terraform, I encounter the error message:
Cannot remove secrets from Container Apps at this time due to a limitation in the Container Apps Service.

The above error usually occurs due to the removal of an existing secret or adding AD authentication to container app.
Alternatively, you can also create the container app deployment using the user identity method.
Here is the updated terraform code with user identity method.

Note: Please ensure that you have role assignment access to assign the acrpull role to the user-assigned identity.

    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name = "RG-Name"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
      name                = "arkoacr"
      resource_group_name = "RG-Name"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "containerapp" {
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      name                = "containerappmi"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
     
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "containerapp" {
      scope                = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
      role_definition_name = "acrpull"
      principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.containerapp.principal_id
      depends_on = [
        azurerm_user_assigned_identity.containerapp
      ]
    }

    resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "example" {
      name                       = "container-Environment1"
      location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_container_app" "container_app" {
      name                         = "demo-container"
      container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.example.id
      resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      revision_mode                = "Single"
      ingress {
          external_enabled = true
          target_port = 5000
          traffic_weight {
            percentage = 100
            latest_revision = true
          }
      }
     identity {
        type         = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.containerapp.id]
      }
      registry {
        server   = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server
        identity = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.containerapp.id
      }
    
      template {
          container {
            name   = "app-container"
            image  = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/sample/hello-world:v1"
            cpu    = 1
            memory = "2Gi"
          liveness_probe {
            transport               = "HTTP"
            path                    = ""
            port                    = 5000
            initial_delay           = 30
            interval_seconds        = 30
            timeout                 = 15
            failure_count_threshold = 3
          }
        }
        min_replicas = 1
        max_replicas = 3
        
      }
    }

Terraform apply:

After running the terraform code, the container app has been created successfully with existing registry image.

Reference:
Cannot remove secrets from Container Apps at this time due to a limitation in the Container Apps Service
